# NGINX with NJS for token validation

Tags: nginx, oauth-2.0, njs

I am trying to use NGINX auth_request and NJS to validate the OAuth token. I also want to validate the token based on the parent request's `$request_method`, but I am not able to get the original request's method. Instead I am receiving the internal auth request's method and URI.

```
Requested method is GET /_oauth2_token_introspection
```

Is there any way to get the original request's `$request_method` and `$request_uri`. I referred to https://github.com/nginx/njs-examples/blob/master/README.rst#authorizing-requests-using-auth_request-httpauthorizationauth_request but the "r.method" is always GET even if the original parent request is PUT/POST.

I also tried to send it using headers and read it in NJS code, but it is always "undefined"

```
location = /_oauth2_token_introspection {
        internal;
        
        proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_set_header        X-Original-URI $request_uri;
        proxy_set_header        X-Original-METHOD $request_method;
        js_content oauth2.introspectAccessToken;
    }
```

Can someone help me in this regard

Answer (score 0):

Using `r.variables.request_uri` and `r.variables.request_method` in my NJS script worked for me. For more details, refer https://github.com/nginx/njs/issues/100